# Why SubmitChanges doesn't work?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, linq

I'm retrieving data from my database using a custom stored procedure:

```
tbTextBox.Text = db.getSettingValue("PropertyName").First().Value;
```

(db is a global `DataClasses` object, initialized in the `FormLoad` event)

This part works completely fine and it's repeated in a loop (30 seconds interval on timer)

If a user changes the value of the text box, following code is being triggered:

```
private void tbTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tbTextBox.Text != db.getSettingValue("PropertyName").First().Value)
    {
                db.Settings.Where(n => n.Name == "PropertyName").First().Value = tbTextBox.Text;
                db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

If I create object before `submitChanges` and change its value - the same result. I've debugging it and it's NOT like it's never going through my IF statement ;)

Why isn't it working? No exceptions there... There aren't any changes in the database if I query Settings table using SQL Server Management Studio.

**EDIT1:**

```
db.Settings.Where(n => n.Name == "AvailablePeriods").First().Value = tbPeriods.Text;

var a = db.Settings.Where(n => n.Name == "AvailablePeriods");
var b = a.First();
var c = b.Value;

b.Value = tbPeriods.Text;

var d = db.GetChangeSet();

db.SubmitChanges();
```

I've divided code to smaller steps in order to debug it properly. Everything works fine but... Changeset returns no updates. For next step I'll try to use "Attach" as suggested.

**EDIT2:**
Adding PK solved the problem. Everything works as charm now.

Lesson learned - I shouldn't trust myself too much :)

Comment: What does the datacontext log say?

Comment: _'it's like it's never going through my IF statement'_ - Have you debugged and confirmed the event handler is being executed, and whether or not the condition is being evaluated?

Comment: it's NOT like... typo - sorry

Comment: @leppie - how to check that? Where I can find such log?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment - yes, SubmitChanges() is being executed. I've debugged my own code. It's faster than posting on a website...

Comment: This using [this code](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/07/30/linq-to-sql-log-to-debug-window-file-memory-or-multiple-writers) to create a Debug Text Writer Then it'll log the SQL it generates. myDataContext.Log = new DebugTextWriter(); You copy and paste that into your Management Studio and can play around with it till it works

Comment: that helped a lot - in the log only select queries are visible.

Comment: I mean I can see enteries when Stored Procedure retrieves the data and when I select the data in lambda expression, but there's no UPDATE. Looks like SubmitChanges() does not see any differences, so it's not sending them to SQL...

Comment: If there's no update in the SQL generated, try using the Attach() method on the dataContext to update the field

Comment: Attach is the key to display actual exception - which isn't even logged :/ I thought I have got primary key in this table, I was wrong. Attach returned unhalted exception with following message in it "Can't perform Create, Update or Delete operations on 'Table(Setting)' because it has no primary key." I'll modify table and see how it goes...

Comment: @MikeyMouse - post your comment as answer and I'll accept your solution, as it was the major step in the investigation and I was able to track the issue only because of your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating data directly of the Data Context isn't way to update tables. Use the [Attach Method](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2007/12/25/117984.aspx) if the data already exists or InsertOnSumit if it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

This record:

```
db.getSettingValue("PropertyName").First()
```

Is possibly not the same as this record:

```
db.Settings.Where(n => n.Name == "PropertyName").First()
```

---

You are calling First without specifying an order - so the database gets to choose and it doesn't have to choose consistently.

---

You should do less in one line so you have more information available as you step through the code.

---

> it's repeated in a loop (30 seconds interval on timer)

Is that on a different thread?  Did the value of tbTextBox.Text change between the execution of the if-criteria and the if-block?

Comment: Both records are the same, as there are only 2 rows in this table. Moreover first column is unique, so I won't be mistaken in future.

Comment: And I'm using First(), only to tell debugger/compiler that It's one object, so I can get VALUE in my hands :)

Comment: TESTED - timer doesn't affect anything.